# Adding EventListeners to multiple buttons that are attached to array items

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a simple tally counter that creates the same set of buttons for each person in the 'names' array.

**Javascript**

```
var names = ["Andrew", "Ryan", "Brandon", "Jason", "Justin", "Sarah", "William", "Jonathan", "Stephanie", "Brian", "Nicole", "Nicholas", "Anthony", "Heather", "Eric", "Elizabeth", "Adam", "Megan", "Melissa", "Kevin", "Steven", "Thomas", "Timothy", "Christina", "Kyle", "Rachel", "Laura", "Lauren", "Amber", "Brittany", "Danielle", "Richard", "Kimberly", "Jeffrey", "Amy", "Crystal"];

function Buttons() {
    var List = document.getElementById('container');
    List.innerHTML=''
    names.forEach((name) => {
        List.innerHTML += name + '<div> <div class="counter">0</div> <button class="add">Add</button><button class="minus">Minus</button><br><button class="reset">Reset</button></div>'
    });
};

Buttons();

let counter = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");
let add = document.querySelectorAll(".add");
let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".minus");
let reset = document.querySelectorAll(".reset");

add.forEach(addButton => {
    addButton.addEventListener('click', addCounter);
});

minus.forEach(minusButton => {
    minusButton.addEventListener('click', minusCounter);
});

reset.forEach(resetButton => {
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetCounter);
});

function addCounter() {
    counterNum = counter.innerHTML
    counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counterNum) + 1
}

function minusCounter() {
    counterNum = counter.innerHTML
    if (counterNum == 0){
        return false
    }
    counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counterNum) - 1
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter.innerHTML = 0;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Tally Counter</h1>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the buttons nothing happens. It only works on the first person when I change queryselectorAll to just queryselector on the counter variable. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a variable called 'counter' and assigning it an HTML collection of div elements (all the class='counter' elements). So your click listener functions don't know which counter to effect.

The best way to access an element (like a counter div) that is associated with other elements (like buttons) is to use a relative path, something like: *When a button is clicked, find the counter that is grouped with it and modify that*. You can do that with `closest()` (which traverses the parents of the element until it finds a match) combined with `querySelector()`

Here is a slight rewrite, hopefully showing you how you can minimize your code for legibility and also access the counter you need.

```js
const names = ["Andrew", "Ryan", "Brandon", "Jason", "Justin", "Sarah", "William", "Jonathan", "Stephanie", "Brian", "Nicole", "Nicholas", "Anthony", "Heather", "Eric", "Elizabeth", "Adam", "Megan", "Melissa", "Kevin", "Steven", "Thomas", "Timothy", "Christina", "Kyle", "Rachel", "Laura", "Lauren", "Amber", "Brittany", "Danielle", "Richard", "Kimberly", "Jeffrey", "Amy", "Crystal"];

function getCodeBlock(name) {
  return `<div class='block'>${name}<div> <div class="counter">0</div> <button class="add">Add</button><button class="minus">Minus</button><br><button class="reset">Reset</button></div></div>`
}
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = names.map(getCodeBlock).join('')

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let counter = e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.counter');
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add')) counter.innerHTML = +counter.innerHTML + 1;
    else if (e.target.classList.contains('minus')) counter.innerHTML = +counter.innerHTML - 1;
    else if (e.target.classList.contains('reset')) counter.innerHTML = '0'

  })
})
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tally Counter</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
```